# What are my options to deploy different ruby versions to a server?

Tags: ruby, deployment

The Linux server I'm deploying a web application to has a rather outdated version of Ruby (1.8.7) in their repositories, and it doesn't look like that's going to change any time soon.

What are my options in terms of using other ruby versions than the distro sanctioned package in a production environment?

If I was to use something like `rvm`, how would that affect my deployment process, server management, and stability?

Comment: RVM and Capistrano are good places to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**rvm** or **rbenv** are your best bets for managing multiple ruby versions.

As long as you setup RVM/rbenv for the user you're going to be deploying to, this will work fine.  In fact, I've done this myself on AWS with Capistrano.

Comment: `rbenv` looks precisely like what I was looking for. Thanks!